# How to import the react-native-osc library in a react-native mobile application?

Tags: react-native, expo, osc

I am not able to import from `react-native-osc` library in my react-native project. The import results in an 'undefined' object.

I did install the library with npm:

```
$ npm install react-native-osc --save
```

In the `App.js` script, the object library is imported, anyway when I run the application in an Expo.io environment, the object `osc` is '`undefiend`':

```
import osc from 'react-native-osc';
console.log(osc); // it will log 'undefined' on expo.io Android and expo.io web.
```

How to import the OSC functionality in a react-native project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently react-native-osc does not work with Expo. You need to eject your project from Expo or create a fresh new one with react-native init.